# how can I make git clone fail on password prompt

Tags: bash, git, automation, ubuntu-18.04, prompt

I am git cloning ~3000 repositories in a bash script like this:

```sh
    [loop-sy]
        git clone https://foobar.com 
    [ys-pool]
```

Most of these are public repositories and it works fine, but some of them are private and they return a username and password challenge. Is there a way to just move to the next repo (i.e. fail and get on with it) rather than having the bash script stop for me to enter the username and password.

I have searched high and low, but I have not found an answer yet.

I am running an Ubuntu 18.04 server and have root privileges.

Answer (score 2):

You can set `GIT_TERMINAL_PROMPT` to `0`, which will prevent Git from prompting for credentials.  It will still use any that it can find in any credential helper you may be using, but if those don't work, it will just fail instead of prompting.